# any idea how to show text in multilines in details label of tableview in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want to show multiline text in details label of tableview. I can do this using custom table cell but I want to do it with default.

Any idea?

thanks in advance.

Comment: It's the easiest way to create custom label like details label and make them text color also like details label.

Comment: @KamleshShingarakhiya as I mentioned I need to do it in default cell not customised. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
cell.detailTextLabel!.numberOfLines = 0
```

Comment: should I increase row height also?

Comment: No, use auto layout. self.tableview.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension